# How to Format decimal in C# and keep ending 0?

Tags: c#, format, decimal

In C# how can I format $2,471,450.5 to $2,471,450.**50** (Keeping Zero at the end)

This is the expression I'm using to format it and get this value $2,471,450.5 But I've trouble to display like this $2,471,450.**50**

```
String.Format(culture, "{0:$#,#.##;($#,#.##)}", rdr.GetDecimal(10))
```

Comment: Use `0` instead of `#` [Custom numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: In the formatting specification `#` stands for *optional* digit, `0` - for *mandatory*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the correct expression. Changed # to 0. Thank you for your help.

```
String.Format(culture, "{0:$#,#.00;($#,#.##)}", rdr.GetDecimal(10))
```